# Error installing @kde-desktop package in fedora 23

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

Whenever i try to either install the @kde-desktop or update fedora 23 OS i get this error, any guidance would be appreciated.

```
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
  Cannot download gcc49-4.9.3-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm: All mirrors were tried
```

Comment: what is the exact command you tried?

Comment: sudo dnf install @kde-desktop

Comment: exact command works for me just fine. What have you changed in your repo files? Do you use some non-official repo?

Comment: Yes I've added a couple repos, can't remember their exact names right now tho

Comment: Lets try with only official repos: `sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=fedora --enablerepo=updates install @kde-desktop`

Comment: Thanks it worked like magic for me, please post it as an answer so i can confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try with only official repos:

```
sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=fedora --enablerepo=updates install @kde-desktop
```

You can disable all the others and install using this command.